# Split Bluetooth Music Playback and Phone capabilities?

Tags: bluetooth, a2dp, bluetooth-hsp

I have a car stereo which supports bluetooth phones, but not A2DP audio playback.
I purchased an A2DP adapter.

I have easily paired my *HTC Thunderbolt* to the Cicada which pipes audio to the aux jack in the Juke, and plays back. (Sounds great, incidentally.)

However, upon connecting to the Cicada, the phone is no longer connected to the Juke for phone calls.

Is there a way to tell Android to force send HSP data to the hands-free set, and force all A2DP data to the A2DP adapter? The A2DP tells android it supports HSP and therefore overrides the Juke pairing.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed, it's a pretty relevant question to anyone who wants to use different BT devices for calls and audio playback.

Comment: On my Android version (6.0) there are check-boxes for each paired BT device which select whether it should handle Call Audio and/or Media Audio. Perhaps checking "Call Audio" on the car stereo and "Media Audio" on the A2DP adapter would help?